# SVN strategy for multiple apps in one solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, svn, asp.net-web-api, architecture

So I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle the following scenario.

Currently, I have a VS solution with the following projects:

```
.Data
.Domain
.Service
.Web (.NET MVC)
```

For SVN, day to day work goes in trunk, then individual revisions are merged to a production branch. That has worked great so far.

So now, I'm adding a `Web Api` project to the same solution that will use the Service layer. I'll want the ability to have different versions of the Service  layer live on the `MVC` site and the `Web Api` site, so I created a new production branch for the `Web Api` site.

Here's where my problem comes in. Let's say I update the Service layer for something that only really applies to the `MVC` app, do I merge that revision only to the `MVC` production branch, and just leave it out of the `Web Api` branch? Is it ok that the Service layer in each production branch become very different over time?

I'm also open to other setup suggestions. I know there's the externals concept, but I would like to keep everything in one solution.

Comment: Could you explain why you manage a different Production branch for each project? Are not all the projects part of the same system? Do they have a different roll out schedule?

Comment: @JulienJacobs Not every project, just one for the MVC app, and one for the Web Api app. Yes, I'll want the ability to push live a service layer change to just one of them.

Comment: If the service layer is shared by both the MVC and WebAPI, I would personally prefer to only maintain one production branch to avoid merging into 2 branches with the risk of forgetting some commits some days. I would then manage different release schedules if necessary.